# Were the Huns and Mongols at one point rivals?

Tags: mongol-empire, steppe-nomads, mongols, huns

I recently read an article that suggests that perhaps the Huns invading Rome had once been a foe and eventually conquered and forced to migrate by the Mongol empire,this interesting idea completely changed my concept of the Huns and their war tactics,but is it actually fact?

Comment: The Mongol Empire emerged *almost a thousand years* after the Huns vanished as a identified group... That said, the Mongols were probably descended from peoples that once were in contact with the Huns.

Comment: @Semaphore, I would argue that your comment should be an answer (and should be accepted). If not, then we should close the question as trivial. Thoughts?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I'm ambivalent on closing, but the way it's currently worded does feel a bit trivial to me (pretty easy to look up the Huns and the Mongol Empire on wiki after all). I'll keep it as a comment.

Comment: I am voting to close. The reason is perfectly stated by Semaphore.

Comment: It will be difficult to garner more questions and finish the beta if we insult new users.   I think the site is better served by providing a factual answer with a minimum of abuse (let me hasten to acknowledge that I have dealt out my share of abuse in the past).

Comment: I think they may have been confused between the Huns and the Hungarians (Magyars). The latter did do battle with the Mongols.

Comment: @setobot5000 - another excellent answer that seems to be a comment <smile>

Comment: Alright, maybe "dumb" question is too strong, it is a logical question at a basic level, however, it still remains that the user has not attempted to answer this question first themselves, and the OP should know that because it is the same requirement on every SE site. Since the OP has the +100 bonus XP, it means they have used SE before and should know better than to ask un-researched questions.

Comment: It's still pretty much all speculation, right? iirc they haven't even ascertained if the Huns are connected to the Xiongnu or not, so their origins are still mostly indeterminate.

Comment: @setobot5000 - There is indeed no consensus in relating the Huns to any other historical people, including the ones the Chinese historians saw from their vantage point. Lots of nifty possibilities, but those are best left to fiction writers for now.

Comment: OK...it took me a while (kinda slow today for some reason), but I remember where I heard something similar to this now. **This did actually used to be a serious theory**. Updated my answer.

Comment: @setobot5000 The Magyars battled with the Mongols some 300 years after their settlement in Europe. I.e. they were like any other European nation at that time, not nomads.

Comment: @Greg yeah, I was just speculating on why somebody might think the Huns and Mongols had any contact at all. T.E.D. came up with a better theory though.

Comment: The topic of this discussion escapes me. Is the current refugee from Syria crisis caused by Crusades? Same kind of question.

Comment: sorry everyone.I've just finished reading a biography of Atilla the hun and i agree this is a terrible question.Apparently the Xiongnu who most scholars seem to agree were most likely ancestors of the Huns,had left Mongolia hundereds of years before the Mongols arrived.

Answer (score 11):

When most people think of "Huns" and "Mongols", they are thinking of [Atilla's empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunnic_Empire) of the mid 400's and Genghis Khan's [Mongolian Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_Empire) of the 1200's. Since there's a good 800 years between them, obviously the answer is "no" on that level.

It sounds like what you heard is the story of the [Yuezhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuezhi). As you can probably tell from the name, we know about them through Chinese records. In the 2nd century BC the Chinese report they were defeated by the [Xiongnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiongnu). The Xiongnu were based in Mongolia, but predated the Mongol people by a long ways (and are actually yet another candidate for the ancestors of the Huns).

The larger part of the Yuezhi were chased westward. There used to be a serious theory that these were the people westerners called "Huns", and this is how they came to be in the Caspian Sea area that we find the Huns in 600 years later. My sainted [Penguin Atlas of Ancient History](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140513485) shows this on one of its maps. I couldn't find a copy online, but here's an intermediate map from that book that postulates the Huns being in the position they'd have to be in if they were descended from the Yuezhi (for historiographical purposes only!). Note that the date is actually prior to any historical record of the Huns, so this is just his supposition.

[image]

However, that theory is [one of many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huns#Origin), and not a particularly favored one these days either. As of now **there is no consensus on who the Huns were, or where they came from, and this is *not* one of the leading theories**. Even Mr. McEverdy "corrected" this in the "New ..." edition of his atlases. If you look at the ones for sale today, the Huns do not appear on any map prior to 362AD, when they appear in western sources.

Comment: Wow, I never realized Finns had such a big empire...

Comment: @Greg: They probably did not - that looks more like an assumed  linguistic area (including the ancestors of modern Hungarian - not related to the Huns) which probably would have been split into small groups like the Germanic speakers, but with no written records to indicate what was where.

Comment: @Henry The ancestors of Hungarians most probably has only lingual connection to the Finns, but no (or little) blood connection. But I agree that this map is an (unfortunate) mixture of political borders, and borders of ethnic and lingual groups.

Comment: You are correct. In general, the maps in Colin's books show cultural borders rather than purely political ones. The areas that denote actual states have solid lines around them. The shadings are linguistic-based, with related languages having the same theme (eg: hashed for Afro-Asiatic, parallel lines for Indo-European), although sometimes he drops the shading for clarity's sake. There's a very lengthy discourse on his mapping strategy at the start of his books, as understanding it is obviously key to understanding his maps.

Comment: ...That "Finn" area should probably be taken as the extent of [Finno-Ugric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finno-Ugric_languages) (aka: "Uralic") people. IIRC, their culture was mostly based on raindeer herding, with a bit of hunting-gathering thrown in. So that's basically saying they were living across this basic area (which we know due to modern linguistic data), and we don't have any information about anyone else living up in that area at that time. ...back in the '50 when this old map was made. There would have been a page of explanation for each map page explaining details like this.

Comment: @T.E.D.: I don't understand what is the point of answering a total nonsense.

Comment: @Alex - If you have a general discussion you'd like to have about posting strategies, it should probably be raised on [meta](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @T.E.D. Thanks for the elaboration. It makes more sense from that angle.